# R count total dates in each row that are later than a certain date

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with dates in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

I want to count the total values in each row that are later than `2021-05-22 00:00:00`, exclude the `ID` and `creation_date` column, and add a new column `date_count` with the count.

This is the data frame I have:

```
ID    creation_date         date1        date2        date230

1     2021-03-04 06:40:37   2021-03...   2022-06...   2022-06
2     2021-03-05 04:24:43   2021-04...   NA           NA
3     2022-03-19 20:37:07   2022-05...   2022-06...   NA
...
563   2022-04-23 20:59:45   2022-05...   2022-05...   2022-06
```

This is the desired result:

```
ID    creation_date         date1         date2        date230       date_count

1     2021-03-04 06:40:37   2021-03...    2022-06...   2022-06...    123
2     2021-03-05 04:24:43   2021-04...    NA           NA            123
3     2022-03-19 20:37:07   2022-05...    2022-06...   NA            123
...
563   2022-04-23 20:59:45   2022-05...    2022-05...   2022-06...    123
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you might those dates in a variety of formats. You should [edit] your question to add the output of str on the dataframe.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).